# Get CSV values next to similar values

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV exported from 010editor that contains verticies that I need to write a collada dae. Below is one of the lines that are in the CSV.

`struct vertex vertices[0],0.155394 -0.275150 1.110958,124h,6h,Fg: Bg:,`

I need to get all coordinates that are next to `struct vertex vertices[0]` ignoring the number in the square brackets. The numbers that are in the square brackets increase as so:

`struct vertex vertices[0]`,`struct vertex vertices[1]`, etc...

An expected result from:

`struct vertex vertices[0],0.155394 -0.275150 1.110958,124h,6h,Fg: Bg:,
struct vertex vertices[1],0.204020 -0.211455 1.171480,12Ah,6h,Fg: Bg:,`

would be:

`0.155394 -0.275150 1.110958 0.204020 -0.211455 1.171480`

Comment: The numbers in the square brackets are indexes, right? Basically it is the output of a array "vertices", wich consits of the structure vertex. If so, what have you tried? What is happening or not happening?

Comment: Look for the right bracket ] followed by a comma, then look for the second comma after that.  Extract everything in between and split on space...

Comment: Exactly. So far all I do is just copy the column and paste it in from excel. I haven't found enough on CSV to do anything interesting.

Comment: Idle_Mind, there are multiple categories. I have vertex, vertexnormal, vertextexture, and triangles. I'm assuming I could do what you said but add vertex to to begining.

Comment: Show more examples, then, for a better answer.  You could search for the type, surrounded by spaces, to figure out what each line contains.

Answer (score 0):

I found what worked for me. It seems to work just as well if I did it another way.

```
string[] tri = Array.FindAll(obj1,element => element.StartsWith("tri",
                       StringComparison.Ordinal));

foreach (string trinum in tri)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(trinum);

                    al5.Add(trinum);
                }
```